# How do I add a λ hook to my clojure emacs setup when using anonymous function syntax?

Tags: emacs, clojure, lambda, installation, hook

I'm setting up a Clojure emacs environment and it's starting to look pretty sick. The `(fn [x]...)` syntax autocompletes into `(ƒ [x] ...)`, due to one of the packages I have installed. I would just like to add the same kind of effect but for the `#(func % %2)` syntax, to make it `λ(func % %2)`.

Could somebody please tell me which file in which package I need to edit to make this happen?

These are some of the basic things I have installed:
starter-kit,
clojure-mode,
paredit,
cider,
rainbow-delimiters,
rainbow-mode,
popup,
cider, 
clj-doc,
typed-clojure-mode,
auto-complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to arrange something like this to be called in your `after-init-hook`, modify to suit. Note that this can mess up the indentation of files for readers that don't have similar customizations.

```
(dolist (mode '(clojure-mode clojurescript-mode cider-mode))
  (eval-after-load mode
    (font-lock-add-keywords
     mode '(("(\\(fn\\)[\[[:space:]]"  ; anon funcs 1
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "λ")
                       nil)))
            ("\\(#\\)("                ; anon funcs 2
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "ƒ")
                       nil)))
            ("\\(#\\){"                 ; sets
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "∈")
                       nil)))))))
```